# Calling a bash script inside another bash script using qsub

Tags: bash, call, qsub

I am trying to run a bash script inside another bash script using qsub (since I need to run the actual problem on a cluster).

Here is a demonstration of this problem. I have two scripts as follows:

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
sh ./script2.sh
```

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "It works fine!"
```

Now if I put these two scripts in a folder and use command `sh script1.sh`, it will work fine. But if I use qsub command for running it `qsub script1.sh` it will through an error:

**sh: ./script2.sh: No such file or directory**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To define the working directory path to be used for the job -d option
>   can be used. If it is not specified, the default working directory is
>   the home directory.

Check your working directory.

```
#!/bin/bash -f
echo "Working directory is $PWD"
sh ./script2.sh
```

You can use `-d` option to fix this.

```
qsub -d <working directory> script1.sh
```